# Refreshing jQuery dialog data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function which opens a jQuery dialog.  The user is able to modify some data fields, like a dropdown and save the result.  That works fine and the parent page is updated through JQ.  Now when the same item is clicked again, the dialog appears without ever hitting the jQuery call and the data is as it was before changed.  How do force the JavaScript to go through the same functions again and call the controller again for the new values?  Let me know if you need code, but there has to be a command to cause the once invoked dialog to refresh it's data.  Is this because of the browser cache?  The code is like this:

```
 function showTourDetails(tourId, row) {
    $("#divSelectedTour").dialog("open");
    $("#divSelectedTour").load('@Url.Action("_SelectedTour", "Tour", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?tourId = ' + tourId);
 }
```

And the div is just an empty div that is filled with the partial view page:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public PartialViewResult _SelectedTour(string tourId)
 {
      SelectedTourModel tour = GetTour(Convert.ToInt64(tourId));
      return PartialView(tour);
 }
```

Comment: are you populating the dialog with a partial view?  can you show your click event code?

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different approaches, this finally worked:

```
 $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
  });
```